# Refer to `this` in function inside mongoDB aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Im trying to query a collection using

```
function activeNow(){
   //some logic
   //return a number between -1 and 7
}

conn.menu.aggregate([
  { 
    $project: { 
      descrizione: 1,
      validity: () => activeNow(this) //refer to current menu
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      validity: 1
    }
  }
]).exec().then(menu => {
  // menu ordered by activeNow result
})
```

Actually it only return fields _id and descrizione like:

```
[ { _id: 59898b6a41e78f02e4206034, descrizione: [ [Object] ] },
  { _id: 598c312bc0035d313c26c68b, descrizione: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Using Node with Mongoose and MongoDB 3.2.8

Comment: You cannot execute JavaScript in an aggregation pipeline. What do you actually "think" you need to do? What is this supposed to achieve? Because whatever you think you need to do can no doubt be achieved in a better way.

Comment: I need to return menu ordered by the result of that function.... basically it takes the menu object and match some properties with the current timestamp

Comment: Show some data and what you need to happen as a question. You cannot use JavaScript functions in an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: As i cannot use javascript in aggregation this question can be closed.... just to know ive solved using this code `.find({}, {sort: menuSorter})`. menuSorter call activeNow on the compared elements